# c# create system tray application that remains in tray after application closed

Tags: c#, windows

```
 private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowInTaskbar = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    }
```

//Its not working to show my application icon in tray on application Exit.

Comment: So you want the icon to stay there in the tray even after application closed. fine how you are closing the application?

Comment: Yes, and i am using the Application.Exit ();

Comment: try to close the forms instead so that your Icon will stay there in the tray

Comment: So what i will use instead of Application.Exit()  ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the user clicks the icon after your application has exited? Your application isn't running, so there is nobody to respond to the click.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how other applications work. Either you keep the application running or you create a seconds (hidden) application that provides the tray icon. See RasmusW answer for the first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit the application, the tray icon goes away.
Also, when you close the last window, the application exits.

You want to minimize and hide the main window instead of exiting. You can do this with `Hide();` somewhere in your Windows Forms code. Then, when the user wants to show the form, just run `form.Show()`.

Comment: Nope, i want that my application icon will stay in the tray even i closed the application.

Comment: As I said: When you exit the application, the icon goes away - there is no longer a running process. You can make a _different_ application which acts like a launcher of sorts. But then that application needs to run.